# How keyword density is calculated in this case?

Tags: seo, keywords, keyword-stuffing

Example:

I have the keyword:

"how to download advanced systemcare 6.3"

And I use the broad match "advanced systemcare 6.3" in my text;

I'ts is counted as 3 times ("advanced", "advanced systemcare", "advanced systemcare 6.3") or 1 ("advanced systemcare 6.3")?

I have this silly question when it comes to counting the keyword density :(

Comment: Why are you counting keyword density?  It isn't an SEO metric that matters much.   I'd recommend making sure that you use a phrase in the title, a heading, and once or twice in the body, but no more, regardless of how long your document is.

Comment: Keyword density is a myth and was never a metric used in search. It is just one of many examples of SEOs misleading the masses with junk. Just write your content for humans and how it makes sense to write for people to read. Don't worry about keywords or anything else. Natural writing is far superior to social engineering a machine. Do use your title tag and header tags as an outline. Your h1 tag should expand upon the title tag. For each header tag, repeat the header tag within your content within your first sentence in a natural way. Do not just cut and paste it. That's it. Simple.